# What is the equavalent of php getallheaders() function in Angular 4/5?

Tags: php, angular, http-headers

What is the equavalent of php getallheaders() function in Angular 4/5 ?

I need to get request headers but i can't find this in Angular. I can get only response headers with Angular.

[I need to get request header parameters when application start not sending get or post request. In picture i need X-MSISDN and X-IMSI parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptRF6.png)

I try Interceptor  class but its only works when i send get or post requests.

Explanation:

I open application with this url : http://localhost:4200/#/
In this time my request header is like this:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: s_fid=07C355F600B90B3D-291EBB86E5858A2F; s_cc=true; gdslv_s=Less%20than%201%20day; s_vnum=1556196774798%26vn%3D7; s_invisit=true; s_ppvl=login%2520sayfasi%2C100%2C100%2C933%2C375%2C667%2C375%2C667%2C2%2CLP; s_ppv=Welcome%253Atarife%253Aanasayfa%2C100%2C100%2C667%2C375%2C667%2C375%2C667%2C2%2CP; s_ppn=Welcome%3Atarife%3Aanasayfa; gdslv=1524831169979; s_getNewRepeat=1524831169981-Repeat; utag_main=v_id:0162fcdd2735001117d070e941e904072002406a00918$_sn:7$_ss:0$_st:1524832969982$_pn:2%3Bexp-session$ses_id:1524831079859%3Bexp-session$_prevpage:Welcome%3Atarife%3Aanasayfa%3Bexp-1524834769972
Host: localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1
X-IMSI: 286026134103281
X-MSISDN: 905499914581

Request URL : http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1524831359435
```

I need to take X-IMSI and X-MSISDN parameters.

Comment: Interceptors work when you make HTTP requests. And that's the way to go. Besides, you are forced to create your response headers at one point. Why not use a sharing service to create and get them ?

Comment: Can you give example for sharing service ?

Comment: Sure, I'm making an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment : you could create a service that is in charge of handling all of your headers. That's also a good practice : you centralize the logic of a feature.

Here is an instance of a service that can do that. It can create JSON headers, append new headers to the list, reset them ... See for yourself.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HeadersManagerService {

  private headers: Headers;

  constructor() {
    this.resetHeaders();
  }

  resetHeaders() {
    this.headers = new Headers();
  }

  newHeader(key, value) {
    this.headers.append(key, value);
  }

  createJsonHeaders() {
    this.resetHeaders();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  }

  getHeaders() {
    return this.headers;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But I dont want create new headers, i just want take request header parameter from my picture in question. I try this and for getHeaders return undefined.

Comment: I don't see images (corporate proxy). That's why SOF recommends not to not post pictures in your question. Could you use plain text to describe your code ?

Comment: I add explanation part to my question.

Comment: No, it is came from header enrichment (single sign on mechanism).

Comment: So if it comes from a **response**, why would you try to get it in your *request* ? And if they are already present in your request, why don't you use this kind of service to store them ?

Comment: It is came from request header and i cannot take this parameters so i cant store in service.

Comment: @Eliseo comment on the question, not the answers : if you comment on the answers, the OP doesn't get notified

Answer (score 0):

PS: Posting as an answer because it's too long for a comment.

Why don't you try like this

```
setHeaders() {
    const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log(options.headers);
    // return options;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

In angular if it is object, for example 
`obj{name:"ABC" , role:"Student"}`  then  `Object.keys(obj);` will return headers